# Fifo [c] Training

Tags: c, fifo

For personal interest in Fifo's and development of programs in C, I am stuck with this exercise obviously I make big mistakes. Fifo's got created but no flow inside, must rely on the protection/close/open mechanism of Fifo's. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int c;
  int fi;
  int fo;
  int stat;
  int pid;
  fprintf(stderr, "Fifo...\n");

  if (mkfifo("FifoA", 0666)==-1) {
    exit(1);
  }

  if (mkfifo("FifoB", 0666)==-1) {
    exit(1);
  }

pid = fork();

  switch (pid) {
  case 0:

  if((fo=open("FifoA",O_RDONLY))==-1)
    {
       perror("error FifoA");
       exit(1);
    }

    close(fi); 
    while (read(fo, &c, 1)>0) {

      c = toupper(c);
      fputc(c,stdout);   
}
    break;
  case -1: 
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
    exit(1);
  default:

  if((fi=open("FifoB",O_WRONLY))==-1)
    {
       perror("error FifoB");
       exit(1);
    }
    close(fo); 
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin))!=EOF) {
      write(fi, &c, 1);
    }
    close(fi);
    wait(&stat);
    break;
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: So the _child_ opens the fifo for _writing_ (`O_WRONLY`) and then _reads_ from it? And the parent opens for _reading_ and then _writes_ to it? That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

Open the fifo after you `fork()`, with `O_RDONLY` in the child, and `O_WRONLY` in the parent. This way, the fifo can know that both its ends are open, and start communication. Remember, fifos are unidirectional, `O_RDWR` doesn't make sense.

You last problem is that you created two different fifos, and expect them to speak to each other.

```
if((fo=open("FifoA",O_RDONLY))==-1)
//...
if((fi=open("FifoB",O_WRONLY))==-1)
```

Should be

```
if((fo=open("FifoA",O_RDONLY))==-1)
//...
if((fi=open("FifoA",O_WRONLY))==-1)
```

A fifo has two sides. One process writes form one side, the other reads from the other. You only need one fifo if your only goal is a write-and-read program.

Comment: Thanks changed it but still nothing in stdout.

Comment: @MagnatSony You confused the parent and the child.

Comment: _while (read(fo, &c, 1)>0) probably doesn't do completely like you expect; read returns 0 not -1 to indicate the EOF._ So the while check is correct.  There need to be 2 Fifo's.

Comment: Why do you think there needs to be two fifos?

Comment: Please the excersise more fully, then